# Load in environment variables when using sudo

Tags: bash

If I perform the following command:

```
sudo -i
mongo -u $MDBUSER -p $MDBPASSWORD
```

I can successfully connect using the mongodb shell.

However:

```
$ sudo 'mongo $MAUTH -u $MUSER -p $MPASS'
sudo: mongo $MAUTH -u $MUSER -p $MPASS: command not found

$ sudo -i mongo $MAUTH -u $MUSER -p $MPASS
Error parsing command line: the required argument for option '--username' is missing
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Where are these variables set?

Comment: is that a typo in the 2nd set of commands -- MUSER and MPASS instead of the initial MDBUSER a nd MDBPASSWORD ?

Comment: Yes, when I originally raised the question I had been fighting the issue for a couple of weeks, and in that time the variables changes. The problem however remains.

Answer (score 0):

To use single-quote syntax, you need to pass the string to the `bash` shell and expose your variables through `env`, e.g.

```
$ sudo env MDBAUTH="$MDBAUTH" MDBUSER="$MDBUSER" MDBPASSWORD="$MDBPASSWORD" \
    bash -c 'mongo "$MDBAUTH" -u "$MDBUSER" -p "$MDBPASSWORD"'
```

Here are few other examples:

```
$ sudo -i env FOO=FOO BAR=BAR bash -c 'grep -e FOO -e BAR <(set)'
BAR=BAR
BASH_EXECUTION_STRING='grep -e FOO -e BAR <(set)'
FOO=FOO
SUDO_COMMAND='/bin/sh -c env FOO=FOO BAR=BAR bash -c grep\ -e\ FOO\ -e\ BAR\ <(set)'
$ sudo env FOO=FOO BAR=BAR bash -c 'echo $FOO $BAR'
FOO BAR
```

---

When using double quotes, you need these variables defined in your local shell (at the time when running the command), e.g.:

```
sudo -i mongo "$MDBAUTH" -u "$MDBUSER" -p "$MDBPASSWORD"
```

To see whether variables are defined and parsed correctly, prefix the whole command with `echo`. If the variables are empty, they need to be set first.